# What is wrong, or what is missing from the following statement?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, independence, wiener-measure

What is missing from the following statement?

If $W$ is a Wiener process, then it has independent increments, which means for arbitrary $$0=t_0\leq t_1\leq ...\leq t_n\leq s\leq t,$$ $$
\left\{ W_{t_{i}}-W_{t_{i-1}}\;(i=1,...,n),W_{t}-W_{s}\right\} 
$$ are independent random variables. In this case, the $$X=\left(W_{u}\right)_{u\leq s}$$ process is independent from $$ W_{t}-W_{s},$$ which is the same if we write $$\mathcal{F}_{s}=\sigma\left(W_{u}:u\leq s\right)$$ is independent from $$W_{t}-W_{s}.$$

Comment: You haven't specified the distributions of the increments.

Comment: But it has normal distribution by definition, isn't it?

Comment: It's the only thing that seems to be missing to me. Otherwise.... I guess you haven't said why $W_t-W_s$ being independent of finitely many other increments is equivalent to it being independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$.